# How to make this auto populate multiple input based on dropdown selection save more than ten(10) in mysql usingPHP

Tags: php, jquery

I created an auto populate multiple input fields based on the dropdown selection. My problem is the 2nd select box is not populating the corresponding input fields. I know this is wrong because the ID's are the same from select1 but how can I make it work? I need to create around 20 or more select dropdown and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
        $db = mysql_select_db("pbiees") or die('Could not select DB: ' . mysql_error()); 
   ?>
   <html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var compInfoArray = new Array();

   <?php
      $query1 = "SELECT * FROM subject ORDER BY course_id";
      $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

      // build javascript array
      while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['subj_id'].'] = new Array();';
        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['subj_id'].']["course_code"] = "'.$row1['course_code'].'";';
        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['subj_id'].']["course_desc"] = "'.$row1['course_desc'].'";';
        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['subj_id'].']["pr"] = "'.$row1['pr'].'";';
        echo 'compInfoArray['.$row1['subj_id'].']["unit"] = "'.$row1['unit'].'";';
      }
    ?>

    function showname() {
        var subj_id = document.form1.subj_id.value;
        document.form1.course_code.value = compInfoArray[subj_id]["course_code"];
        document.form1.course_desc.value = compInfoArray[subj_id]["course_desc"];
        document.form1.pr.value = compInfoArray[subj_id]["pr"];
        document.form1.unit.value = compInfoArray[subj_id]["unit"];
    }

    window.onload=function() {
    showname();
   } 

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form name="form1">  
        <select name="subj_id" onchange="showname()">
        <?php
           $query1 = "SELECT * FROM subject ORDER BY course_id";
           $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

        // build javascript array
           while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row1['subj_id'].'">'.$row1['course_code'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
      </select>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="course_code" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="course_desc" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="pr" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="unit" value="" />
     </label>
     <select name="subj_id" onchange="showname()">
        <?php
           $query1 = "SELECT * FROM subject ORDER BY course_id";
           $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

        // build javascript array
           while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row1['subj_id'].'">'.$row1['course_code'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
      </select>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="course_code" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="course_desc" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="pr" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="unit" value="" />
     </label>
  </form>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using JSON to store your data for JavaScript to handle?

Comment: No, what i meant there is how to store data to mysql database using php. and to make more than 10 auto populate input fields based on the dropdown selection.